# MySQL Linux and Windows entity changes

Tags: mysql, linux, windows

I have a trigger on an entity that copies the row and saves it in a different entity.

I also have 2 MySQL servers one on Linux and the other on Windows. It seems the order of the columns in the same table are different between the servers. Is there a way to make them the same order? Some configuration?

I'm creating an audit table using this script:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx.AuditEntity (
  auditAction VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  auditTime DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  type VARCHAR(64)  NULL COMMENT '',
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  modifiedBy BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  timeCreated DATETIME  NULL COMMENT '',
  currency VARCHAR(32)  NULL COMMENT '',
  nameVARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
   INDEX auditTime (auditTime ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX id (id ASC)  COMMENT '');
```

The trigger on the original entity:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER xxx.entity_AINS AFTER INSERT ON Entity FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN INSERT INTO AuditEntity select 'AFTER_INSERT', now(), e.* 
    from Entity e where id = NEW.id; 
END
```

Because the columns in the 2 servers have a different order it doesn't work.

Our idea is not to explicitly write out the columns' names, is there a difference between how Linux and Windows save entities?

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the table definition, you'll need to do something similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 MODIFY COLUMN Column1 INT AFTER Column2;
```

This will move Column1 after Column2.

[Alter Table Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks but not relevant for my problem, I edited the question

Comment: OK, if you're not prepared to align the tables, change your trigger to include the actual columns: `select 'AFTER_INSERT', now(), e.col2, e.col1, e.col3 from Entity e where id = NEW.id;` or... Update the `INSERT INTO` with the explicit column names.

Comment: our idea is not to explicitly write the columns names, is there a difference between how linux and windows save entities?

Comment: No. The initial creation of the tables on each of the servers has differed here. If you don't want to change the trigger then you must change the definition of the Entity table on either Linux or Windows to match the other. Check the definition of the Entity table on each.